# TypeScript Interface Templating

Tags: typescript, types, interface, code-cleanup

I'm not too sure one correct terms for using TypeScript. But I feel like I'm repeating myself and would like to template my interface better so be less confusing.

I've got a `type` which is basically a list of potential strings. Then I've used those strings in keys for my `interface`.

This is my file:

```
import { IErrorResponse } from '~/interfaces'

export type PRODUCT_ACTION_KEYS =
  | 'creatingProducts'
  | 'fetchingCategories'
  | 'fetchingProduct'
  | 'fetchingProducts'

export interface IProductsReducer {
  categories: any[]
  error: {
    creatingProduct?: IErrorResponse
    fetchingCategories?: IErrorResponse
    fetchingProduct?: IErrorResponse
    fetchingProducts?: IErrorResponse
  }
  is: {
    creatingProduct: boolean
    fetchingCategories: boolean
    fetchingProduct: boolean
    fetchingProducts: boolean
  }
  products: any[]
  selectedProduct?: any
}
```

I'd like to get something like this:

```
import { IErrorResponse } from '~/interfaces'

export type PRODUCT_ACTION_KEYS =
  | 'creatingProducts'
  | 'fetchingCategories'
  | 'fetchingProduct'
  | 'fetchingProducts'

export interface IProductsReducer {
  categories: any[]
  error: {
    [PRODUCT_ACTION_KEYS]?: IErrorResponse
  }
  is: {
    [PRODUCT_ACTION_KEYS]: boolean
  }
  products: any[]
  selectedProduct?: any
}
```

Would something like this be achievable in TypeScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's what [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) are for

```
export interface IProductsReducer {
  categories: any[]
  error: {
    [key in PRODUCT_ACTION_KEYS]?: IErrorResponse
  }
  is: {
    [key in PRODUCT_ACTION_KEYS]: boolean
  }
  products: any[]
  selectedProduct?: any
}
```

Another way to get the same type is to use a combination of built-in Partial and Record types:

```
 error: Partial<Record<PRODUCT_ACTION_KEYS, IErrorResponse>>
```